# Building a "random rectangle"

Tags: probability

Adam and Daniel are building a "random rectangle" using a standart pack of cards $(\spadesuit, \heartsuit, \diamondsuit, \clubsuit)$. Adam takes $6$ cards one by one with return, the number of diamonds cards $\diamondsuit$ will be the length of the  rectangle base. Daniel takes cards one by one with return till he gets "Ace". the number of cards that Daniel took out will be the rectangle hight.

$(A.)$ Find the probability that the area of the rectangle will be $21$

$(B.)$ Find the expected value and the variance of the rectangle **perimeter**.

$(C.)$ Find the expected value and the variance of the rectangle **area**.

---

**My attempt:**

$(A.)$ For area $=21$ I need $3$ cards for the base and $7$ for the hight OR $7$ for the base and $3$ for the hight

The base of the rectangle: (I'm using here binomial distribution)$$P(X=3)=\binom{6}{3}\big(\frac{13}{52}\big)^3\big(1-\frac{13}{52}\big)^{6-3}\approx 0.131835\\
P(X=7)=0$$

The hight of the rectangle:(I'm using here geometric distibution)
$$P(Y=7)=(1-\frac{4}{52})^{7-1}\frac{4}{52}\approx 0.04758\\
P(Y=3)=\text{I don't need to calculate that because }P(X=7)=0\\
\Longrightarrow P(\text{area}=21)=\bbox[yellow]{0.04758 \times 0.131835}$$

$(B.)$

The length  of the rectangle base $\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

The length  of the rectangle high $\in \{1,2,...,48\}$

$$E[\text{perimeter}]=E[2X+2Y]=2E[X]+2E[Y]$$ since that $X\sim B(6,\frac{13}{52})$ and $Y\sim G(\frac {4}{52})$

so $2E[X]=2\cdot np=2\cdot 3/2=3\\
2E[Y]=2\cdot 1/p=26\\
\Longrightarrow E[\text{perimeter}]=26+3=\bbox[yellow]{29}$

$$Var[\text{perimeter}]=Var[2X+2Y]=Var[2X]+Var[2Y]+2Cov[2X,2Y]\\
=4Var[X]+4Var[Y]+2Cov[2X,2Y]\\
4\cdot\frac 3 2(1-\frac{13}{52})+4\cdot \frac{1-4/52}{(4/52)^2}+2Cov[2X,2Y]\\
=\bbox[yellow]{4.5+156+2Cov[2X,2Y]}$$

$(C.)$ let's assume that $X,Y$ are uncorrelated (otherwise I don't know how to solve it) $$E[\text{area}]=E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=(3/2)\cdot 13=\frac{39}{2}\\
Var[XY]=E[X^2] E[Y^2] - [E(X)]^2 [E(Y)]^2. $$

My atemmpt is correct? I don't succeed to finish $(B.)$ and $(C.)$

Comment: Actually $Y$ can take values up to infinity. It is indeed geometric (since Daniel draws with return). And you can indeed assume that $X,Y$ are uncorrelated, actually independent. They draw independently, that is ok. So, Cov(X,Y)=0.

Comment: Unless we are told that it is not allowed, for A) we should also consider the rectangle with base $1$ and height $21$.  For B) there are infinitely many possibilities for the height.

Comment: Actually you already used independence of $X,Y$ in (A), when you multiplied the two probabilities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks a lot

Comment: @JimmyR. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. To finish C), your expression i right, all you need to do is compute. For $E(X^2)$, note this is $\text{Var}(X)+(E(X))^2$. You know the variance of $X$, so you know $E(X^2)$. Same for $E(Y^2)$.